# rendering markdown documents is changing HTML < tags to '&lt;'

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, pixiedust-r

In my most recent build of the `pixiedust` package, my HTML tables stopped rend    ering correctly.  I seem to have isolated the problem to the `<th>` tags being changed to `&lt;th&gt`, and then I get a whole bunch of text in place of the table I should be getting.

Here's a minimal Rmd file that I have saved in "pixiedust_example.Rmd"

````
---
title: "Sprinkles"
author: "Benjamin Nutter"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  rmarkdown::html_vignette:
    fig_caption: no
    number_section: yes
    toc: yes
vignette: >
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{Sprinkles}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
---

```{r, echo=FALSE, results = 'asis'}
cat("<table style = 'border-collapse:collapse;'><tr><th colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style=''>sprinkle</th>\n<th colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style=''>console</th>\n<th colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style=''>markdown</th>\n<th colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style=''>html</th>\n<th colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style=''>latex</th></tr>\n\n<tr><td colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style='background-color:#A6DBA0;'>bg</td>\n<td colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style='background-color:black;'></td>\n<td colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style='background-color:black;'></td>\n<td colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style='background-color:#006837;'></td>\n<td colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style='background-color:#A50026;'></td></tr>\n\n<tr><td colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style='background-color:#A6DBA0;'>bg_pattern</td>\n<td colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style='background-color:black;'></td>\n<td colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style='background-color:black;'></td>\n<td colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style='background-color:#006837;'></td>\n<td colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style='background-color:#A50026;'></td></tr>\n</table><br/><br/>\n")
```
````

When I save that text string to a plain HTML file, I get the table I expect (with a bunch of `\n`'s but I don't think those are contributing to the problem.)

When I generate HTML tables with `pixiedust` in interactive mode, they render correctly in R Studio's viewer pane.  I've tried this with the current version of `rmarkdown` and `knitr` and the previous versions of both packages.

Any idea what might be happening here?

(this is what the table should render to)

```
<table style = 'border-collapse:collapse;'><tr><th colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style=''>sprinkle</th>\n<th colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; 

style=''>console</th>\n<th colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style=''>markdown</th>\n<th colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style=''>html</th>\n<th colspan = 

'1'; rowspan = '1'; style=''>latex</th></tr>\n\n<tr><td colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style='background-color:#A6DBA0;'>bg</td>\n<td colspan = '1'; 

rowspan = '1'; style='background-color:black;'></td>\n<td colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style='background-color:black;'></td>\n<td colspan = '1'; 

rowspan = '1'; style='background-color:#006837;'></td>\n<td colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style='background-color:#A50026;'></td></tr>\n\n<tr><td 

colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style='background-color:#A6DBA0;'>bg_pattern</td>\n<td colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style='background-

color:black;'></td>\n<td colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style='background-color:black;'></td>\n<td colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style='background-

color:#006837;'></td>\n<td colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style='background-color:#A50026;'></td></tr>\n</table><br/><br/>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `htmltools::htmlPreserve`?

Comment: That did it.  Thanks!  Not sure I would have ever thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

This is @Jonathan's answer from the comments:

````
---
title: "Sprinkles"
author: "Benjamin Nutter"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  rmarkdown::html_vignette:
    fig_caption: no
    number_section: yes
    toc: yes
vignette: >
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{Sprinkles}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
---

```{r, echo=FALSE, results = 'asis'}
cat(htmltools::htmlPreserve("<table style = 'border-collapse:collapse;'><tr><th colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style=''>sprinkle</th>\n<th colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style=''>console</th>\n<th colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style=''>markdown</th>\n<th colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style=''>html</th>\n<th colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style=''>latex</th></tr>\n\n<tr><td colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style='background-color:#A6DBA0;'>bg</td>\n<td colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style='background-color:black;'></td>\n<td colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style='background-color:black;'></td>\n<td colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style='background-color:#006837;'></td>\n<td colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style='background-color:#A50026;'></td></tr>\n\n<tr><td colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style='background-color:#A6DBA0;'>bg_pattern</td>\n<td colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style='background-color:black;'></td>\n<td colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style='background-color:black;'></td>\n<td colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style='background-color:#006837;'></td>\n<td colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style='background-color:#A50026;'></td></tr>\n</table><br/><br/>\n"))
```                                                                          `
````